# Firebase - set() doesn't change the value, creates new doc instead

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to create read / unread chat option that will set the read value to true if opened.
When I do click the chat it opens the right db entry but doesn't set the value of read, instead it creates a new doc in my collection with read:true.

```
import {Avatar} from "@material-ui/core";
import StopRoundedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/StopRounded"
import "./Chat.css";
import ReactTimeago from "react-timeago";
import {selectImage} from "./features/appSlice";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {db} from "./firebase";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

function Chat({id, username, timestamp, read, imageUrl, profilePic}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
    const history = useHistory();

    const open = () => {
        if(!read) {
            dispatch(selectImage(imageUrl));
            db.collection("posts").doc(id).set(
                {
                    read:true,
                }, 
                {merge:true}
            );

            history.push('/chats/view');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div onClick={open} className="chat">
            <Avatar className="chat__avatar" src={profilePic} />
            <div className="chat__info">
                <h4>{username}</h4>
                <p>Tap to view - <ReactTimeago date={new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()} /></p>
            </div>

            {!read && <StopRoundedIcon className="chat__readIcon" />}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

Chat shouldn't be available for preview if the read value is true.

Preview that adds values to collection:

```
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {selectCameraImage, resetCameraImage} from "./features/cameraSlice";
import "./Preview.css";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";import TextFieldsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/TextFields';import CreateIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Create';import NoteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Note';import MusicNoteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MusicNote';import AttachFileIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AttachFile';import CropIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Crop';import TimerIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Timer';import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
import {v4 as uuid} from "uuid";
import {storage, db} from "./firebase";
import firebase from "firebase";

function Preview() {
    const cameraImage = useSelector(selectCameraImage);
    const history = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!cameraImage) {
            history.replace('/')
        }
    }, [cameraImage, history]);

    const closePreview = () => {
        dispatch(resetCameraImage());
    };

    const sendPost = () => {
        const id = uuid();
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`posts/${id}`).putString(cameraImage, "data_url");
        uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }, 
        () => {
            storage.ref('posts').child(id).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                db.collection('posts').add({
                    imageUrl:url,
                    username:'Egon',
                    read:false,
                    //profilePic
                    timestamp:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                });
                history.replace('/chats');
            });
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="preview">
            <CloseIcon className="preview__close" onClick={closePreview} />
            <div className="preview__toolbarRight">
                <TextFieldsIcon />
                <CreateIcon />
                <NoteIcon />
                <MusicNoteIcon />
                <AttachFileIcon />
                <CropIcon />
                <TimerIcon />
            </div>
            <img src={cameraImage} alt="" />
            <div onClick={sendPost} className="preview__footer">
                <h2>Send Now</h2>
                <SendIcon fontSize="small" className="preview__sendIcon" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Preview
```

and Chats component that calls Chat function and passes id:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {Avatar} from "@material-ui/core";
import "./Chats.css";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ChatBubbleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChatBubble";
import {db} from "./firebase";
import Chat from "./Chat";

function Chats() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('posts').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ 
            id:doc.id,
            data:doc.data(),
        }))))
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="chats">
            <div className="chats__header">
                <Avatar className="chats__avatar" />
                <div className="chats__search">
                    <SearchIcon />
                    <input placeholder="Friends" type="text" />
                </div>
                <ChatBubbleIcon className="chats__chatIcon" />
            </div>
            <div className="chat__posts">
                {posts.map(({id, data: {profilePic, username, timestamp, imageUrl, read}}) => (
                    <Chat key={id} username={username} timestamp={timestamp} imageUrl={imageUrl} read={read} profilePic={profilePic} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chats
```

Comment: Where is the `id` coming from ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i think directly from firebase

Comment: I cannot see where you are calling the `function Chat()`. Can you share the complete code do were can see what is being passed as ID in there?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i updated the original question

Comment: It looks fine to me. If you are sure that a document exists then ideally you should use `.update({read: true})` instead of `.set()`. Also try making the function async and adding a await on the update operation. Additionally please try logging the `id` just before update operation to make sure the ID is correct. Can you please try that?

Comment: I tried changing the method to update() but the result was the same, then i put entire update part in comments and the logged db.collection("posts").doc(id) and it returned an entire object
ill try to make it async - i'm still slightly inexperienced with async funcitons

Comment: No, I meant just log the value of `id` and not the document reference.

Comment: i tried returning id again with update commented out and it returned the correct id

Comment: not sure if this helps but i got it this way: https://i.imgur.com/b6lZ6fG.png

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I forgot to add id in Chat component while maping them.

```
    <div className="chat__posts">
       {posts.map(({id, data: {profilePic, username, timestamp, imageUrl, read}}) => (
       <Chat key={id} id={id] username={username} timestamp={timestamp} imageUrl={imageUrl} read={read} profilePic={profilePic} />
       ))}
   </div>
```